# google earth - viewing KML file in world map

Tags: kml, google-earth, overlay

I"m using google earth and a KML file that I have generated.  I would like to display all the KML points in a world map.  Google maps online does it but the print is poor.  Need a 300 dpi print which is a secondary issue not related to this.

How do i go about doing that in google earth or equivalent?

Comment: Google Earth Pro (free now) allows higher print resolutions (300 dpi) https://www.google.ca/earth/download/gep/agree.html